# MySQL return result count along with all results or check if query limited

Tags: sql, mysql, limit

I have a query that returns a large amount of results, so i'm limiting the amount returned. But I want to find out if there were more results then the number I limited them to, either by getting all the results back with a count(*) or some way of determing if the results were limited all in the same query as the one that returns the results!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care about how many more rows there are, you can also just add 1 to the limit. 
Say you wanted to display 100 rows per page. So you limit by 101. If at anytime you receive 101 rows, you know that there is at least one more page.

Obviously, you have to discard the extra row each time, which adds some extra complexity to the application code.

Comment: good thinking this idea will work the best as using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is really slow! And i only need to know if there where ANY more results

Answer (score 5):

Use the [FOUND_ROWS function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) after the query that uses the LIMIT:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

From the documentation:

> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT clause to restrict the number of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned without the LIMIT, but without running the statement again. To obtain this row count, include a `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in the SELECT statement, and then invoke `FOUND_ROWS()` afterward:

Comment: ideally I would like to avoid a second query and do it all in the same query but this will work if the former isn't possible

Comment: The second query is just to retrieve the value calculated by the first query. It is the appropriate solution for your problem and was designed exactly for it.